# What is the inverse function of the Log Gamma function?

Tags: gamma-function

What is the inverse function of the Log Gamma function?

$\log\Gamma(x)$

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogGammaFunction.html

Can it be inverted, and why not, if not?

Comment: Try to solve $\text{log$\Gamma $}(x)=0$

Comment: Mathematica tells me it is $x=2$, together with an error message.

Comment: When you write \text{log$\Gamma $}(x), you don't get proper spacing.  I changed it to \log\Gamma(x), which gives you $\log\Gamma(x)$ and is standard usage. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: What do you think $\log\Gamma(1)$ is? $\log\Gamma(2)$?  Then look at the curve in your original link

Comment: @Henry : You should also read my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

$$\log(\Gamma(x))=y$$

Then, solving for $x$, we get:

$$x=\Gamma^{-1}(e^y)$$

And then this is where you put in a formula for the inverse of the gamma function.

Comment: Note that $\log\Gamma$ is not injective.

Comment: @mrf Then we already know that this will produce an infinite amount of values for almost all input $y$.